# How to mosaic MODIS hdf files using Python GDAL?

Tags: python, hdf5, gdal, mosaic

I have downloaded large amounts of MODIS hdf files and extracted needed bands from each file.How can I mosaic all the hdf files together using GDAL lib in Python and reproject it?Thanks!

Comment: Try [gdal_merge.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html) followed by [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) to reproject it.

Comment: Ok, I might as well drop that down in the answer area ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two GDAL command line tools:

1. [gdal_merge.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html) to mosaic the bands into one raster
2. [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) to reproject the raster

Answer (score 0):

You could try also pyModis [0], it is using Python GDAL in the development version (from today, I need to test it more).

gdal_merge.py doesn't work with MODIS HDF (probably it is a bug), this is the returned error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gdal_merge.py", line 510, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/bin/gdal_merge.py", line 390, in main
    file_infos = names_to_fileinfos( names )
  File "/usr/local/bin/gdal_merge.py", line 122, in names_to_fileinfos
    if fi.init_from_name( name ) == 1:
  File "/usr/local/bin/gdal_merge.py", line 147, in init_from_name
    self.band_type = fh.GetRasterBand(1).DataType
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'DataType'
```

[0] https://github.com/lucadelu/pyModis

Comment: If gdal cant open a file, you probably are providing either the wrong pointer to the dataset or you are missing the driver necessary to open the file type.